# Install Anywhere 2011 - Disabled Field

Tags: installation, installanywhere

Is there a way to disable based on another user input field?

For example, can a checkbox enable a file input field?

Grae

Comment: InstallAnywhere and Windows-Installer are mutually exclusive technologies.  Please remove the unrelated tag so we can better answer your question.

Comment: Just trying to cast a wide net.  The number of people who follow install anywhere is

Comment: But it doesn't do any good. If you net a guy like me I'm going to start talking about using conditional expressions in WindowsInstaller ControlConditions to create the relationship and that wouldn't do you a bit of good.  If you aren't getting help here I suggest going to http://community.flexerasoftware.com/ as they have an InstallAnywhere forum with plenty of recent activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in standard panels, you probably will need to create custom console/panel